# Soundness of Calculus?

Tags: analysis, logic, soft-question, math-history

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Weierstrass) wikipedia article. It talks about the "soundness of calculus", but it seems to talk about soundness in an informal sense and how analysis/calculus was not very rigorous and not the soundness in logic it linked to.

My questions is, assuming the article didn't make a mistake, how was Weierstrass's contribution in "modernizing analysis" related to the "soundness of calculus"?

Comment: Yrs, it is quite informal; but "soundness" means consistent+true axioms.

Comment: The issue is with the use of [infinitesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal#History_of_the_infinitesimal) in the calculus with the well-known critique about using "vanishing quantities" in operations, that amounts to dividing by zero. Obviously, dividing by zero is an "unsound" operation.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA if *that's* what they meant by soundness I guess this more or less answers my question